# How to fix duplicate files after changing case using Visual Studio Code with the Vitest extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vitest

I created a file `TestSTepCell.test.tsx` using Visual Studio Code and after spotting the typo, I renamed the file to `TestStepCell.test.tsx`.

Now, using the [Vitest extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vitest.explorer) I see both files:

[image]

And the file explorer there is only one file:

[image]

If I click the 'go to test' button on the red test case:

[image]

A tab is opened with the wrong file:

[image]

I really want to get rid of the test case with the file type.

I have tried deleting the directory with the files, uninstall the Vitest extension, delete the `node_modules` directory (which may hold a vitest cache IIRC) and restart my Mac (to ensure any ts-server was restarted). Then after restart, I copy back the correct files in that directory, reinstall Vitest extension. Problem persists.

I have `ignorecase = false` set in my git config.

I am on a Mac OS 11.7.8,
vscode 1.87.0

Comment: This describes the issue too I think, but not any answer? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121106

Comment: So this tells me, that the cause of this is by design and there are no fixes :o/ https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3236

Comment: what if you delete the sqlite database of the workspace, VSC keeps track of the files open in the workspace and other stuff, on windows it is stored in `c:\Users\__name__\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\`, find the dir for your workspace and delete/rename the `.vscdb` files

Comment: Restarting VS Code often helped me with this kind of problem. And only rename files using the VS Code.